# Launch an App by hardware key press in windows phone10

Tags: windows-10-mobile

How to launch the windows app using hardware key when the phone in locked state. need hardware key event to trigger action in windows 10 or 8.1 windows store app .

Answer (score 0):

Instead
**Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;** you need use  **var systemNavigationManager = Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();** which contains **BackRequested** event

Also you can add extension library and use API for Windows Phone 8.1 Store App
[image]

**if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))**

**Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;**

But when device was locked your application go to suspend mode and you cannot handle events

Comment: I want  to handle when the device is locked.  Capture the  key combination and  trigger  an action  in  my  app

Comment: I think this impossible for Windows Phone 8.1 Store App

Comment: OK for  using  back button. I need  to  check that  to  sdk extention  but  it  is missing in my 2015 VS.  How  to  do that  can  u guide for this